# Default values when 'grouping by' when there's no data produced by the query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Suppose I want to select the largest `value` for the `timestamp` < XYZ for a list of `grps`. E.g. given the following table `table`:

```
+---------------------+-------+-----+
| timestamp           | value | grp |
+---------------------+-------+-----+
| 2012-02-01 00:00:00 | 1     | 3   |
+---------------------+-------+-----+
| 2012-02-02 00:00:00 | 2     | 3   |
+---------------------+-------+-----+
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | 3     | 4   |
+---------------------+-------+-----+
```

The query `SELECT grp, max(value) FROM table WHERE timestamp <= '2012-02-01 00:00:00' AND grp IN (3, 4) GROUP by grp;` results in

```
+-------+------------+
| grp   | max(value) |
+-------+------------+
| 3     | 1          |
+-------+------------+
| 4     | 3          |
+-------+------------+
```

All good. By I want the query to return 0 for `value` if there's no data for the given `timestamp` range for a particular `grp`.

`SELECT grp, max(value) FROM table WHERE timestamp <= '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND grp IN (3, 4) GROUP by grp;` results in only one row, containing no data for `grp = 3`. How do I write a query which would have zero for it instead, producing the following result?

```
+-------+------------+
| grp   | max(value) |
+-------+------------+
| 3     | 0          |
+-------+------------+
| 4     | 3          |
+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to join your groups to your maxes using an inline queries like so and use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT grps.grp, 
       COALESCE(values.val, 0) val 
FROM   (SELECT grp 
        FROM   table 
        GROUP  BY grp) grps 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT grp, 
                         Max(value) val 
                  FROM   table 
                  WHERE  timestamp <= '2012-02-01 00:00:00' 
                  GROUP  BY grp) values 
              ON grps.grp = values.grp
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdb5d/2)

If your groups are in a table you don't need inline queries at all just a good left join

```
SELECT
  grps.grp,
  COALESCE(max(value),0)
FROM
  groups grps
  left join `table` t
  on grps.grp =  t.grp
   and  timestamp <= '2012-02-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY
  grps.grp
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf9eb4/6)